# How can set up a directory listener to copy a file

Tags: linux, shell-script, file-copy

I would like to create a Bash script that will sit and listen to a directory and when a new directory or file is added it will recursively copy each file to another location. For example:

- I could set the script to sit and listen to my home dir `/home/`
- Then when I added a new directory `test`, containing `test.txt`
- The script would copy `test/test.txt` to, say, `/home/user/Desktop/test`

I can not install `inotifywait`. Is this possible?
Thanks

Comment: is there a reason why you cannot get `inotifywait` ?

Comment: Seconded. `inotifywait` (or something related, such as `incrontab`) is the obvious solution here

Comment: Its just not available on the system im using. I have been trying to do it with a while loop using the watch command but cant seem to get it right

Comment: Show the code with which you tried.....  And what kind of linux system is not capable of installing a package which contains `inotifywait` ?

Comment: How do you plan to deal with a new file that is created, but has not finished being written when you notice it is available? You are likely to get partial files frequently.

Comment: I dont have the necessary permissions to install on the system. I have been using this `if [ $(ls -1A $inPath | wc -l) -gt 0 ] ;then cp -r $inPath $outPath;` in a while loop. But it requires you to know how many files in the directory to begin with.

Comment: So get your sysadmin to install the package.

Comment: A `while` loop with no `sleep` will keep one of your CPUs 100% spinning all the time. With some `sleep`, you'd get polling, which in turn is better accomplished with cron (or equivalent). Also, are you only interested in top-level new directories? What about changes inside them? Should a new file in an existing directory trigger a copy? Finally, should files and directories be copied even if they already exist on the destination? Please, [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/580919/edit) new information into your question instead of including it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is have a cronjob that runs every hour, which uses a function like below, of courseyou could use a different time.

```
find /home/user/ --mmin -60 -exec echo This file changed: {} \;
```

This will output every file that was modified in the time given, for the example above 60 minutes.

This is a example I came up with. It copies the directories where changes happened, it only copies the root upper most directory so its not extremely efficient.

```
find /home/name/* -maxdepth 0 -mmin -60 -exec cp -r {} /some/other/dir/ \;
```